# Cannot find 'fake' package from k8s.io/client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes, dependency-management, client-go

I have the dependency in my go.mod file like below:

```
    require ( 
       ...
       k8s.io/client-go v0.23.1
    )
```

I deleted the entire vendor folder and tried updating the dependencies like this:

```
    go mod tidy 
    go mod vendor
```

But still fake is not present as can be seen from the pic below:

[image: Vendor content of k8s.io]

Also from here i can see that the 'fake' pkg is present - https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/kubernetes

Comment: What is that picture supposed to be showing us? Do you have a compilation error? If you don't import a package, it is not required to be stored anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

just add a blank import statement like:

```
import (
    _ "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/fake"

    "k8s.io/client-go/discovery"
)
```

and execute the command

```
go mod vendor
```

and you will see the expected folder

```
>ls vendor/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/
clientset.go doc.go       fake         import.go    scheme       typed
```